# JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, postman

I am sending request to external service which has updatedDate property

```
@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name = "updated_date")
private LocalDateTime updatedDate;
```

When I receive the response in my DTO I am trying to format the LocalDateTime property like this

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
private LocalDateTime updatedDate;
```

But I get error in Postman

```
"message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String \"2020-04-14T10:45:07.719\": Text '2020-04-14T10:45:07.719' could not be parsed at index 14; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String \"2020-04-14T10:45:07.719\
```

Comment: Your pattern is completely fine, i could reproduce `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse("2020-04-14T10:45:07.719")` it does not throw any error. Maybe there is a problem with jackson.

Comment: If you are using Lombock, In some cases you need to add the following annoations `@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are milliseconds in the input string, so your format should be "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"

Update:
If the millisecond part consists of 1, 2, 3 digits or is optional, you may use the following format:

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS][.SS][.S]")
private LocalDateTime updatedTime;
```

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS" Made it work but if the milliseconds are two digits instead of 3 which happens every 10 requests it fails again

Comment: @GeorgiMichev Have you tried without the `pattern`? I believe the default format is what you want, with dynamic number of fractional digits.

Answer (score 7):

You can remove the annotation @JsonFormat and let it works in a default way. It is working fine for me even if I removed the millisecond.

```
@NotNull
@FutureOrPresent(message = ErrorMessages.INVALID_CAMPAIGN_START_DATE)
//@JsonFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
private LocalDateTime campaignStartDate;
```

JSON Request:

```
{  "campaignStartDate" : "2020-12-31T15:53:16",
  "campaignExpDate" : "2021-01-24T15:53:16",
}

{
  "campaignStartDate" : "2020-12-31T15:53:16.45",
  "campaignExpDate" : "2021-01-24T15:53:16.45",
}

{
  "campaignStartDate" : "2020-12-31T15:53:16.445",
  "campaignExpDate" : "2021-01-24T15:53:16.445",
}
```

These JSON requests will work fine.

Comment: This is a very helpful and interesting answer - works perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, I used this one with "pickupDate":"2014-01-01T00:00:00"

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime pickupDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck for several hours tried every answers I found over the internet. I had to delete `'.SSSZ'` or `'.SSS'` part after `'...HH:mm:ss"`.

**Didn't work**
`@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)` OR
`@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS][.SS][.S]", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)`

**Worked with**
`@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)`
`private LocalDateTime dateTime;`

And setting headers in Postman
`Content-Type: application/json`
`Accept: application/json`

Comment: I can confirm accepted answer works for optional milliseconds. Are you sure you are using LocalDateTime? Also make sure you are using java 8+.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this because my JSONproperty setter was not properly handling null.

```
e.g. 

    @Column(name = "equipment_purchase_date")
    private LocalDate purchaseDate;

bad:
    @JsonProperty
    public void setPurchaseDate(String dateStr) throws ParseException 
    {
        this.purchaseDate = LocalDate.parse(dateStr, df);
    }

good(Fix):
    @JsonProperty
    public void setPurchaseDate(String dateStr) throws ParseException 
    {
        this.purchaseDate = dateStr == null ? null : LocalDate.parse(dateStr, df);
    }
```

thought i would include this as none of the above answers were applicable in this case.