# Formatting date retrieved from JSON file in Java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, date, jackson

I import a JSON file and try to format date properly. But every time I try a different combination as mentioned on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61202937/json-parse-error-cannot-deserialize-value-of-type-java-time-localdatetime-fro) or some similar threads, I always get "Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "09.09.1977": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate" error.

Before fixing the problem, I think I need to be clarified about the following questions (I need to format Date in "**dd.MM.yyy**" format):

**1)** Does the date field have in the JSON file to be a specific format?

**2)** I have entity and dto classes where my date field is located. Should I apply related format annotations, etc. in these classes on the date field as shown below?

Here are some examples I tried:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy", iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
private LocalDate startDate;
```

Or how can I format the read json file in "dd.MM.yyyy"? Here is the related code block where I retrieve the file and convert from `EmployeeRequest` request to `Employee`:

```
final List<Employee> employees = requests.stream()
                .map(EmployeeRequestMapper::mapToEntity)
                .toList();
```

Comment: You are probably using a wrong (de-)serializer, have a look at them: The result is expected to be a `LocalDate`, which perfectly matches the `String` to be (de-)serialized. The only thing that does not match is the `LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class` you have applied, it expects a time of day apart from the date. Check if you can find a `LocalDateDeserializer.class`… Oh, and the `@DateTimeFormat` should not be `DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME`, I think.

Comment: @deHaar Thanks, but I do not use all of these annotations and just need what is the proper annotations. I do not use time as it is not present in my JSON. SO, how should I format and where should I use the related annotations?

Comment: @deHaar Any idea about these issues?

Comment: Change to LocalDateSerializer…

Comment: **You** don't use the (de-)serializers, but the framework does and if it uses the wrong ones, there will be errors like the one you mentioned…

Comment: @deHaar  How should I change? What change to? Why do not post an answer? Sorry, but I have really no experience.

Comment: **I had done everything you suggested** and use `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy", iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)` and `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")` only for Employee entity and EMployeeReuqest. But still the same. ARe you sure that your suggestion will work?

Answer (score 0):

### [tl;dr] Use the same data type on class level and in annotations

You currently try to use an automatic de-/serialization of a `String` that represents a date (**only** year, month of year and day of month). For this to work automatically, you need to annotate the class member with the classes that are responsible for serialization and deserialization. The one you are currently using is a `LocalDateTimeSerializer`, though it should be a `LocalDateSerializer`, because the current one will expect a time-of-day part in the `String` to be (de-)serialized, which it hasn't and your target class is a `private LocalDate startDate`.

In my opinion (not tested), your code should look like this:

```java
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy", iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDate startDate;
```

Comment: **1.** Thank you so much for all of these useful explanation. It did not work, but I think by making some twes, will work. First of all, is it ok to have dates in "dd.MM.yyyy" format in JSON file?

Comment: **2.** I add these annotations to `startDate` fields in `Employee` entity and `EmployeeReuqest` classes. Is that enough?

Comment: **1.** yes, it's totally ok to have `String`s like `"dd.MM.yyyy"` in your JSON files. That's why there is the possibility of setting custom patterns in the `@JsonFormat`.

Comment: **3.** I hope there is no problem with mapping on `final List<EmployeeRequest> requests = mapper.readValue(resource.getFile(), new TypeReference<>() {});`

Comment: **2.** That might be enough, but I can't tell you that for sure… I don't know your project. I would try and read error messages (carfully) when they occur.

Comment: **3.** Hope so, too… No idea ;-)

Comment: Do you have any idea about the following error message? >>> Resolved [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "09.09.1977": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '09.09.1977' could not be parsed at index 0<EOL> at [Source: (File); line: 1, column: 111] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.company.dto.request.EmployeeRequest["startDate"])

Comment: No idea, parsing it directly in code does indeed work with this pattern…